# Prove vector space decomposes into direct sum of $-1$ and $+1$ eigenspaces of a linear map $P:V \to V$ such that $P^2=I$.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> Let $V$ be a vector space and $P:V \to V$ be a linear map such that $P^2=I$. Then $V$ decomposes as the direct of the $+1$ and $-1$ eigenspaces ($V^+$ and $V^-$ respectively) of $P$.

My attempt

Let $V^+=\ker (P-I)$ and $V^-=\ker (P+I)$.
It's true that $V^+ \cap V^- =\emptyset$.

It's obvious that $V^+ \oplus V^- \subset V$.

Now let $v \in V$.  $v$ can be written as $v=\frac{1}{2} (v+Pv)+\frac{1}{2} (v-Pv)$.
Then $$(P-I)\left( \frac{1}{2} (v+Pv)\right) =\frac{1}{2} \left( Pv +P^2v-v-Pv \right) $$
$$=\frac{1}{2} (v-v)  =0$$

so  $\frac{1}{2} (v+Pv) \in V^-$.

Similarly for $V^+$.

Is this correct?

Comment: Actually, $V^+\cap V^-=\{0\}$.

Comment: That shows that $V^++V^-=V$. To complete it, assume that $v\in V^+\cap V^-$. Then $Pv=-v=v$. therefore, $2v=0$. If the field of coefficients has characteristic different from $2$, then $v=0$. Note that in characteristic $2$ we would have $V^+=V^-$. So, the statement would be false, in that case.

Answer (score 0):

If $P^2=I$, then
$$
         x=\frac{1}{2}(x-Px)+\frac{1}{2}(x+Px) \\
          = x_{-1}+x_{1}
$$
where $Px_{-1}=-x_{-1}$ and $Px_{1}=x_{1}$.